# How to check for a React route inside ExpressJS server.js?

Tags: node.js, regex, reactjs, express, routes

I have a particular route defined for my React application. I want to check it in my server.js because there is a particular call I need to do, but I can't use an AJAX call due to some reason.

The route is something like this: `some-slug/asset/some-more-sluggish-matter/`

`/asset/` is going to stay constant. Here is what I have tried:

```
app.get('/(.* )?(\/asset\/)(.* )?', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Route found');
});
```

Doesn't work. If I remove the quotes it throws an error that the regex is unterminated.

Comment: You seem to confusing express routing with react routing. `<Route path="/asset" component={AssetPage} />` Simply tells React to render that particular component if the url in the browser matches "/asset". The code you have given above is expressJS code which says that if the URL of an incoming GET request matches this, run this code. Can you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks @ManavM, I am clear about the routes on both the ends, I simply want to match the fragment after the root url to make a server side API call.

Comment: I see...The problem with the way you have defined the above path is that you have defined it as a regex but used single quotes instead of forward slashes so express is reading it as a string..You should also be escaping every forward slash (your first one is not escaped) ...If you want to use regex, then your path should have been defined like `/\/(.* )?(\/asset\/)(.* )?/`.

Comment: Adding a different regex as an answer since I think that is a more accurate regex

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the way you have defined the above path is that you have defined it as a regex but used single quotes instead of forward slashes so express is reading it as a string..You should also be escaping every forward slash (your first one is not escaped)...

Your path should have been defined like `/.*(\/asset\/).*/`.